# UIWebView loadHTMLString format

Tags: iphone, rss, uiwebview, format

I'm new to the whole "iPhone Dev" world, and I am creating a simple app which has a feature to see the latest entries from a number of different Wordpress blogs.

I am able to grab encoded content ( node) from the RSS feeds and display it easily enough using a UIWebView and the loadHTMLString function.

What I cannot figure out how to do right now is change the look of the text in any way, shape, or form... I don't think it's possible for me to change the data coming back in the RSS feed, so I need to know how to do it in the code.

Thanks!

--d

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to change the appearance.

One is to modify the html before passing it to loadHTMLString.  For example, you could insert a `<link href="local.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` just before `</head>` using simple string replacement.  You could do the same thing with a `<style>...</style>` tag.

```
html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</head>" withString:@"<link ... /></head>"];
```

Another way is to call `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` in `webViewDidFinishLoad` and do whatever you want with javascript.  You have full access to the [DOM](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/) through javascript and can manually create styles and assign classes.

You may need to use both together.